# Thesis advisor saw me doing really well without being pestered too much, but now I need the pestering (I need his input basically)

Tags: thesis

My supervisor was away for a few weeks, saw (let's say at time=1) that my thesis was progressing really well, and I guess he decided it's best to leave me with minimal supervision. We talk maybe once every 3-4 weeks now, and to be honest now is the time that I actually really need his advice. Contacting him is impossible, thus I turn here now in hope of some help.

The first problem is I'm running out of things to write. When he initially showed the topic, I was under the impression that I will be taking approaches A and B which I genuinely like and enjoy (I was recommended to do my thesis with him precisely because I like approaches A and B). But his recent results smashed a lot of small results that uses approaches A and B, making them irrelevant. I did try to include older material that is at least useful, but I'm really running dry on material (even to read). There is an approach C, but it uses theories outside the scope of an undergraduate, and I no longer have the time to read up on the theories first.

The second problem is that I'm feeling that my thesis is kind of, well, too simple. I feel like I could've written the core material (apart from the linear algebra parts) in high school. Graph theory often feels like this though, and this is why I need his opinion. I'm currently writing another section that is only related to the main topic if you squint hard enough, with the sole reason that the section acts as a 'difficulty anchor'. By that I mean I just want to demonstrate that I can do a little mathematics too. I don't know how ridiculous this is.

Maybe there is a question implicitly from the last two paragraphs, I really don't know. I find that I also can't explicitly formulate the question, since I don't even know what is my question. Maybe I'm just looking to clear doubts.

Answer (score 2):

Your paragraph ending with a reference to approach C suggests that this is an undergraduate thesis.

If that's the case, I think you may have little to worry about. Undergraduates are not usually expected to prove new theorems in their theses.

You don't say why it's impossible to contact your advisor. Perhaps he has some good personal reason. Perhaps you need his help less than you think you do.

I suggest that you write up what you did with approaches A and B, independent of the fact that your advisor has proved things you were working on. Be sure to cite his work. If you can reprove theorems a different way, that's a good thing. Sketch out further ideas in your "difficulty anchor" chapter.